# Using custom Browser Keyboardshortcuts

Tags: browser

I am looking for some hints/examples how to get Keyboardshortcuts working for my Browser.

Lets take Internet Explorer 7 to get an Idea how this can work...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Applications can define keyboard shortcuts using Access Keys:

```
<a href="..." accesskey="s">Save</a>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" accesskey="s" />
```

The modifier you have to press to trigger the shortcut is different in each browser, take a look at the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key) for more information.